# How do I change my loading screen banner in StarCraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I recently resumed playing StarCraft 2, and I've noticed that several of my opponents have had a number of different banners above their name on the loading screen.

[image]

I remember these previously just being based on what race you selected, with each race having a different fixed banner. That's still what I see above my name (below), but my opponents seem to be selecting from a larger selection of banners.

[image]

However, these banners aren't listed under any of the categories in the "Collections" tab.

[image]

How can I change the banner that appears above my name in StarCraft 2 loading screens? How do I unlock new ones, and how do (can?) I switch between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Banners *can* be changed under the "Augments" section of the "Collections" tab. I just didn't notice it the first time I looked.

[image]

As of February 2019 there are five banners available for each of the four races. Two are unlocked for all players, the others are unlocked in conjunction with different one-time events.

Comment: is it possible to use a custom image as banner?